# PHP echo out id with the same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

[image]

What I want to do is to query/echo out those id with the same value for example id 1 and id 3 has the same value. Is that possible in the same table and column? Thanks!

Comment: I think you could group by weight, then in the select group_concat(id).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self-join to get all pairs of IDs with the same weight

```
SELECT t1.weight, t1.id AS id1, t2.id AS id2
FROM YourTable AS t1
JOIN YourTable AS t2 ON t1.weight = t2.weight AND t1.id < t2.id
```

or `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the IDs with the same weight in a single row:

```
SELECT weight, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY weight
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To get just one pair for each weight:

```
SELECT t1.weight, t1.id AS id1, t2.id AS id2
FROM YourTable AS t1
JOIN YourTable AS t2 ON t1.weight = t2.weight AND t1.id < t2.id
GROUP BY t1.weight
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e00/1)

Comment: Hi, what if I have 3 same values in the column but only want to echo 2 id's? Is that possible

Comment: Use the first query and add `GROUP BY weight` so you only get one pair for each weight.

Comment: Hello I am using the first query but I'm getting this error  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'weight' in field list is ambiguous'

Comment: Great, now problem now is I have several same values, but only 1 pair shows up with this query.

Comment: Yes it does work, but my problem is I have many equal values that looks like this. http://i.imgur.com/2WOQwny.png as you can see there are four 50 values. But when I query it using your query, it only shows the first two 50 combination and the other two doesn't.

Comment: That's what you said you wanted: "if I have 3 same values in the column but only want to echo 2 id's". So I only show the first two.

Comment: But what if I want to echo out another pair?

Comment: Make up your mind. Do you want to echo all the pairs or just one? I gave you both queries in my answer, use the one that you want.

Comment: With this data http://i.imgur.com/2WOQwny.png and using your 2nd query, I am getting this output http://i.imgur.com/IiLrjZS.png but what I wanted is like this http://i.imgur.com/xlJLgl8.png

Comment: Why isn't `3,7` in your desired output?

Comment: I am making a weight matching like system in  which I am matching those who have the same weight/value. But I want only for example four 50's, I only want 2 pairs. For example I have ten 50's, I want 5 pairs (No repeating value)

Comment: What happens if you have an odd number of people with the same weight?

Comment: There may be a way to do that in SQL, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. It will probably be much easier to do it in PHP. When you're processing the result, put the IDs in an array. Before echoing each row, check whether either ID is in the array, and then skip it.